# jQuery returning empty string as ID for This

Tags: javascript, jquery

Working with a server-side table, I am trying to build an array of rows that have been selected while toggling the class .active in each of those rows.

"this" seems to be correct in that it is returning the selector that has been clicked.  However, this.id is always an empty string ("").  What am I doing wrong?

```
var active = [];
$('#adminstable tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
    var id = this.id;
    var index = $.inArray(id, active);
    if ( index === -1 ) {
        active.push( id );
    } else {
        active.splice( index, 1 );
    }
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
} );
```

Comment: You're sure the TR has an ID ?

Comment: The id is being returned as "", not undefined. There is nothing that I have in the row that would be considered an id, however.  My thinking is that was an HTML function.  Am I mistaken?

Comment: If no `id` is assigned, an empty string will be returned.

Comment: Is that something that I do and how?

Comment: They are asking if your `<tr>` have a defined id, for example: `<tr id="some_id_here">`

Comment: To be clear, this is in support of a server-side process.  Rows will be displayed at a selected number on each page, default 10.  The total number of rows will be 1000's.  Each one of the total rows would have to be tracked in the array.  If we are talking about selector ID's, that is going to be fun to try to do...

Comment: Alright, I guess I will have to go that route.  It makes sense, I assume.  The code came from DataTables.  It left out that part of the equation.

Comment: Well, you could always use the `<tr>` index as a sort of row identifier. Server side coders shouldn't haven an issue placing an id, since it's probably a result set iteration.

Comment: Okay, now that you mention it, I can generate the ID on the server side and pass it along in a non-displayable format.  Thanks.

Comment: Here is what I'm getting at: [.index()](http://api.jquery.com/index/)

Comment: @SparoHawk I understand.  It looks like it is unique within a page.  I'll have to generate it to get it unique within all my rows.  Thanks.

Comment: Since this is DataTables, I simply had to add 'DT_RowId:"Row_" + item.id.to_s' to the response hash and it inserted the id I needed.  Who wants to post the final answer?  Do it and I'll accept it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is DataTables, I simply had to add

```
DT_RowId:"Row_" + item.id.to_s
```

to the response hash and it inserted the id I needed.

Answer (score 0):

the `this` is referring to the `<tr>` and it doesn't have an ID, does it? if not, that seems to be the issue.

try:

```
var id = $(this).parents('table')[0].id;
```

Comment: That generates the id of the table and is very interesting.  I need to id each row.  Now that I have entered this question, the answer seems basic.  I have to generate it and pass it...

Comment: oooohhhh. ok. i totally misunderstood. and lol on the epiphany. Happens to the best of us, man.